# Can I use mixed conditional type 2 in any situation?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Just like the title, can I use mixed condition type 2 in any situation?
Or could it be used in some particular situation?

Ex) If you came here, you would have had snacks. These kind of sentences.

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make logical sense. "If you came, you would have" or "If you had come, you would have had".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In casual speech, no problem, at least in the US. In formal writing it must begin with “if you had come here”.